# jQuery filtering divs based on multiple data attributes

Tags: jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple divs on a page, each with the following data attributes: data-one, data-two, data-three, data-four & data-five. The following code is creating a `filterList` array like so: `['one-value', 'two-value', 'three-value', 'four-value', 'five-value']` depending on which values are selected in the five dropdowns. Building of the `filterList` array is working.

However some of the divs have multiple data attribute values, i.e. `data-one="one-value,one-value-2,one-value-3"`

If the divs contain only one data attribute value, it seems to work fine, but it's not working when there are multiple values separated by a comma.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```js
var filterList = [];

jQuery("#jsonFilters ul#one ul li a.active").each(function() {
  var dataOne = jQuery(this).attr("data-one");
  filterList.push(dataType);
});

jQuery("#jsonFilters ul#two ul li a.active").each(function() {
  var dataTwo = jQuery(this).attr("data-two");
  filterList.push(dataTwo);
});

jQuery("#jsonFilters ul#three ul li a.active").each(function() {
  var dataThree = jQuery(this).attr("data-three");
  filterList.push(dataThree);
});

jQuery("#jsonFilters ul#four ul li a.active").each(function() {
  var dataFour = jQuery(this).attr("data-four");
  filterList.push(dataFour);
});

jQuery("#jsonFilters ul#five ul li a.active").each(function() {
  var dataFive = jQuery(this).attr("data-five");
  filterList.push(dataFive);
});

if (filterList.length == 0) {
  jQuery('.div').removeClass('hidden');
  jQuery('.div').fadeIn();
  console.log('No Filters');
} else {
  jQuery('.div').each(function() {
    offeringOne = jQuery(this).attr('data-one');
    offeringTwo = jQuery(this).attr('data-two');
    offeringThree = jQuery(this).attr('data-three');
    offeringFour = jQuery(this).attr('data-four');
    offeringFive = jQuery(this).attr('data-five');

    if (jQuery.inArray(offeringOne, filterList) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(offeringTwo, filterList) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(offeringThree, filterList) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(offeringFour, filterList) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(offeringFive, filterList) != -1) {
      jQuery(this).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      jQuery(this).hide();
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> Now if we just had some HTML here...</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet of your code with jQuery  added - but not of much use without the related HTML.  Please edit it to add the HTML you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data-attribute values contain string values that represent lists of offerings delimited by commas, you will need to `split` those values into arrays so you can compare *each* offering value against the `filterList`.

You could re-write your `jQuery('.div').each` handler to something like the following:

```js
var filterList = [
  'one-value',
  // 'one-value-2'
];

if (filterList.length == 0) {
  jQuery('.div').removeClass('hidden');
  jQuery('.div').fadeIn();
  console.log('No Filters');
} else {
  jQuery('.div').each(function() {
    const isVisible = ['data-one', 'data-two', 'data-three', 'data-four', 'data-five'].some(attr => {
      const attrValue = jQuery(this).attr(attr);
      if (!attrValue) { return; }

      const offerings = attrValue.split(',');
      
      return filterList.every(offering => offerings.indexOf(offering) > -1);
    });
    
    if (isVisible) {
      jQuery(this).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      jQuery(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-one="one-value,one-value-2,one-value-3">
  Div One
</div>
<div class="div">
  Div Two
</div>
<div class="div" data-one="one-value">
  Div Three
</div>
<div class="div">
  Div Four
</div>
<div class="div" data-one="one-value-2">
  Div Five
</div>
```

Comment: This is great but the filters don't work together - they work independently!

Comment: @onesixty I don't understand what that means. Could you explain further?

Comment: Hi - so if i use dropdown A and select Value A - it works and shows only the divs with Value A. But then when i choose a second Dropdown B, it ignore that value doesn't filter down further. Basically all five dropdowns are supposed to filter like AND, rather than OR

Comment: @onesixty I think that what you are looking for can be achieved by replacing the `filterList.some` with `filterList.every`. I have made that change to the code snippet in my post.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got there in the end my combining all details in 1 single data attribute then using a filter. Your code worked great and helped massivley!